# Difference between (bool) and (boolean) in php?

Tags: php

What is the difference between:

```
$state = (bool)0;
```

and

```
$state = (boolean)0;
```

Both return the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean is an alias for bool. Both of them mean that same type of variable.